# How does a search engine discover/crawl a website page when requested URL loads the content via database?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, sitemap, django

I am creating a new blog website in Django. All the posts and their details are stored inside an SQLite database (one that comes default with Django). Once a post's URL is requested, the server returns the webpage which contains the post loaded from the database. My question is, since the webpages do not exist until someone types in the URL, how will a search engine such as Google crawl the website and make it show up in the search results if it is relevant to the search? Is it necessary to provide a sitemap for this to happen?

Comment: You should definitely provide a sitemap.  If there are internal links, crawlers will follow the links.  If there is nothing linking to a page then it won't be found.

Comment: "until someone types in the URL" - Do you not provide any links to your pages?

Comment: Just because the pages are dynamically generated doesn't mean you don't know which pages will or won't exist ahead of time.   Hopefully your site is configured to return "404 not found" errors when the user requests non-existant content.